# How WPF layout deals with text wrapping

Tags: wpf, text, word-wrap

WPF layout works by first asking controls to measure themselves, and then arranges the controls based on the desired size they produced during the measure stage.

I do not see how it is possible to deal with text wrapping in this case.

A control that contains text to be wrapped must know its width before it can calculate its height. But at measure stage width is unknown. It will be assigned by the arrange stage, when all measuring is completed. So the height cannot be calculated during measure.

How does text wrapping work in WPF?

Comment: "But at measure stage width is unknown." Then what do you think is the [`availableSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.measure(v=vs.110).aspx) parameter for? Keep in mind that layout is done recursively.

Comment: @Clemens is correct. The available width is passed in during Measure. So the wrapped text will will the width then expand down.

Comment: @Clemens availableWidth is the total available width in the parent container before any layout is done on the children. The final width assigned to the text control will not necessarily have the same value as availableWidth. If it had, the measure phase would be redundant. The text control does not know its actual width until Arrange is called on it.

Comment: The layout of the text with wrapping is done based on the available width in the measure phase. If the rare situation where the final width is less than that then the text will be truncated in the x dimension, it won't recalculate wrapping, as you seem to be implying that it will.

Comment: "availableWidth is the total available width in the parent container before any layout is done". I'd suggest you try the following: Create a FrameworkElement-derived class, override its MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride method, add some debug output of the sizes and call the base class methods. Then you put that element in a 2x2 grid which fills the windows area. Play around with the window size and observe the debug outputs.

Answer (score 0):

This very simple custom TextBlock shows how it works:

```
public class MyTextBlock : FrameworkElement
{
    private FormattedText formattedText;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Text", typeof(string), typeof(MyTextBlock),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                null,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure,
                (o, e) =>
                {
                    ((MyTextBlock)o).formattedText = new FormattedText(
                        (string)e.NewValue,
                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                        FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                        new Typeface("Segoe UI"),
                        24,
                        Brushes.Black);
                }));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        var size = new Size();

        if (formattedText != null)
        {
            formattedText.MaxTextWidth = availableSize.Width;
            size.Width = formattedText.Width;
            size.Height = Math.Min(formattedText.Height, availableSize.Height);
        }

        return size;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        if (formattedText != null)
        {
            formattedText.MaxTextWidth = finalSize.Width;
            formattedText.MaxTextHeight = finalSize.Height;
        }

        return finalSize;
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);

        if (formattedText != null)
        {
            drawingContext.DrawText(formattedText, new Point());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that WPF text controls assume that final size of the control will be the same as availableSize during Measure phase. If this is not true, the text layout will be wrong and text will be truncated. As this is a rare occurrence and can be prevented by tweaking parent container controls if needed, it is acceptable.

Comment: @Clemens Your code returns desired size for the control from MeasureOverride based on text layout generated assuming the control will have size of availableSize. The parent control will then assign finalSize for the control. In ArrangeOverride you re-layout the text based on finalSize. If finalSize is narrower than availableSize was, your text will no longer fit, as it will take more space vertically than was calculated in MeasureOverride. Your control should have been taller, but you had no way of knowing that finalSize will be narrower than availableSize.

Comment: So where is your real-word example (i.e. code) of this situation? The important point is that MeasureOverride never returns a Size that is larger than availableSize. It must be a malicious Panel that would arrange a child element with a size smaller than what it just passed to its Measure method. Even then, the TextBlock would be rendered correctly, because the FormattedText's bounds are updated in ArrangeOverride.